# C++ reading information from a file and building a 2dimensional vector from that information

Tags: c++, file, input, vector, 2d

Text file is formatted as shown below:

2 columns 2 rows all * go
(four more rows like this)

For each row of text, I need to build a 2D vector based on the information given in the line of text and output to the console. For example, the output of the first line of text would look like this:

**

**

I can read the information into my program; however, I don't know how to get any further. How do I categorize the information so that the program knows that the vector needs to have 2 columns and 2 rows?

Any tips or help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Post your code. Show us what you tried.

Comment: Is there any specification for the line?  Is it always `X columns Y rows all Z go`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to parse the input and get your information from it. Now, there are libraries for that, like [boost::spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) but if you need only this simple case then there would be no need of using such a large library for only one case.

I would suggest a simple splitting of the input string to words, like this:

```
string input = "2 columns 2 rows all * go"; // Read it from some input
istringstream iss(input);

vector<string> tokens;
copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
     istream_iterator<string>(),
     back_inserter<vector<string> >(tokens));
```

Then the `tokens` are your words. So if you expect that the first word is for the columns and the third one is for rows then you can do:

```
int columns = atoi(tokens[0].c_str());
int rows = atoi(tokens[2].c_str());
```

I think you can figure the rest out.

Hope this helps.